# Consume java web services in vb6 using winsock

Tags: vb6

I am sending data to webservice but it is getting failed with out of memory. So, is there any possibility to send data in chunks to the web service. Can I use winsock to consume webservice and upload data in chunks to the java rest service api?

I have tried multiple way like sending data with single byte array but everything got failed. Now the hope is on winsock, please help.

```
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + enc
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & 
          strBoundary
        .send (sPostData)
        Do
                DoEvents
               If .WinsockState = sckClosed Then
                  PostRequest = False                   
                  Exit Sub
               End If
                .send (StreamFile)


            Loop Until m_bStreamFinished = True Or g_bAbortHTTP = True

        response = .Status
    End With
```

Expecting to use winsock to upload a file to java webservice but I am not able to do

Comment: What do you mean by "winsock"? You are using Microsoft.XMLHTTP not the socket networking layer directly.

Comment: I don't want to use microsoft.xml http. Can I use winsock instead of that

Comment: Please check here for Winsock library https://www.codeguru.com/vb/controls/article.php/c19505/Using-the-Winsock-Control-in-ClientServer-Applications.htm

Comment: Isn't winsock a much lower-level networking library? Why do you prefer to do it that way?

Comment: Because Winsock has a flexibility to transfer data in chunks. With http post that is not possible

Comment: I just meant that if you are connecting to an HTTP source, 99% of the time a normal HTTP library would be the thing to use. You may have special requirements, of course. You might want to edit the question to expand on your circumstances, people may be able to provide better help that way.

Comment: Here is a sample winsock http downloader you can base your uploader on: https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/contrib/cHttpDownload.cls

Comment: Can I use winsock for webservice connection? Or only for http server?